# Create new git repository excluding history but allow merges back

Tags: git, version-control

I have a tricky Git situation. I have a single Git repository, that I now need
to share with another organization, and allow them to modify and submit changes
back to me (and keep updated with future changes I make). However, there are a
number of files in the repository that contain proprietary information which I
legally cannot disclose. I can't remove these files from the repository
entirely, since they are critical for things I am presently working on.

Ideally, I would move the proprietary files into a separate repository/library,
but that will be a minor refactoring project and I'd like to avoid it if I can.
Currently, proprietary and non-proprietary files are all intermingled throughout
the same directory structure.

My goals are as follows

1. Provide them a repository without any proprietary files. I don't care if they
   don't have access to the revision history, it can be a "fresh" copy with just
   one commit.
2. Allow them to submit new commits back to me to update my repository.
3. (Ideally) Allow them to accept new commits from me, containing only changes
   made to the non-proprietary files.

Is there any way to do this in Git, while still allowing me to have a single
repository with proprietary and non-proprietary components?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for
[a Git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).
One way to go about it would be

- `clone` your repo inside of itself
- `cd` to parent repo, `git submodule add <child repo>`
- the child repo will be for the private files, `git rm` other files to avoid 
  duplicates with the parent repo

Now in the parent repo, you will need to `git filter-branch` out all the private files. This is controversial step because it will rewrite the history all the way back to the first commit of a private file.

Finally you can maintain both repos, and share the parent repo without worry.

Answer (score 0):

(this is a complete rewrite of an earlier answer)

```
git checkout -b sanitized master
# do your sanitization work
git commit
git tag sanitization-prep
git checkout --orphan distributable
git commit
git checkout sanitized
git merge -s ours distributable
git tag distributable-base
git checkout master
git merge -s ours sanitized
```

That `-s ours` merge marks all the changes you did as already merged into master, without actually applying any of them. Since the distributable commit has no parents, nothing but that will be sent when you push that branch to the DMZ'd repo they'll be working in.

When it's time to pull changes from the distributable branch

```
git checkout sanitized
git merge distributable
git checkout master
git merge sanitized
```

There is one caveat: you have to have done that `merge -s ours distributable-base` into every branch that you're going to be merging distributable into. Other than that, your work is perfectly ordinary.

I got a fair way into a procedure for outbound merges.  The one I have so far is horrifying.